# How would I add a line space after displaying a user input

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a site with html and js where the user inputs some text and after they enter it, it displays on the screen. How do I have it so that after every time the users input gets displayed, a line space gets added?

```
function doME() {
     nav.innerHTML = 'Welcome  ' + answers.value;
     Chatbox.innerHTML += " " + cbox.value;
}
login1.addEventListener('click',doME);
```

line four is where it displays what the user inputted, i want to add a linespace after the user input **

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include your code as a Stack Snippet?

Comment: What is a "linespace", do you mean line-feed/new-line?

Answer (score 0):

Add HTML to the end of your javascript function **doME**:

```js
function doME() {
     nav.innerHTML = 'Welcome  ' + answers.value;
     Chatbox.innerHTML += " " + cbox.value + "<br/>";
}
login1.addEventListener('click',doME);
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```js
function doME() {
    nav.innerHTML = `Welcome ${answers.value}`;
    Chatbox.innerHTML += ` ${cbox.value}<br/>`;
}
login1.addEventListener( 'click', doME );
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).